# Do I need to create Primary Keys on tables for Symmetrics DS replication?

Tags: oracle, postgresql, replication, symmetricds

I have a 2 databases: oracle & postgres. I need a replication on same tables from oracle to postgres.
I'm trying to do this with primary keys or without it.
If without PK then Symmetrics transfers the table incompletely or doubles the rows. I don't see any errors in the log files.
With PK it seems the replication going normally. I tried about 10 times.
How do you think Primary Keys is really important for Symmetrics's replication?

Comment: What database are you doing your test on? When there are no primary keys SymmetricDS considers all the columns part of a virtual primary key.   You can run into issues with updates using all columns as the key.   There is a setting on sym_trigger to set a "virtual" key (sync_key_names).

Comment: I'm testing oracle <-> postgres databases. I found the phrase in the doc: "Specify a comma-delimited list of columns that should be used as the key for synchronization operations. By default, if not specified, then the primary key of the table will be used." Is this means that I should set a list of columns(in sym_trigger table) or having a primary key?

Comment: Yes that is correct if you have a PK there is no need to set this sync_key_names.  If your table does not have a PK this provides the virtual method as mentioned above and the columns in this sync_key_names field will be used instead.

Answer (score 1):

Opinion based answer, obviously.

Usually, a primary key (generally speaking) is very important. It prevents you from doing *stupid* things as it uniquely identified a record & can't contain NULL values, so the database itself won't let you insert invalid data.

It is *good news* that replication failed (for some rows - which were, obviously, invalid - either PK columns weren't unique, or some of them were NULL). It is *bad news* that you got duplicates (which you probably don't want). So, pick what you find the most appropriate - have it nice, clean and safe, or vice versa.

BTW, what's the point in having *invalid* data, anywhere - either in your source or target database? You never know whether some info you're looking at is valid or not. You'd rather not have it at all.

Comment: I know that Primary Keys is very important :) Symmetricsds is announced that can replicate both kind of tables: with or without primary keys.